# Orchard Custom forms: Is it possible to send a file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

Orchard custom fors are great.

I have converted an old aspx form and works great.

However I'm stuck now.

On my project I could easily add a file and send as attachment to form mail target.

Is it possible to do in Orchard custom forms?

As additional detail: all anonymous users should be able to do so...

I have tried media picke and content picker but did not the trick...

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to create your own secure image upload field.